# Unexpected results when using printf

Tags: c, type-conversion, printf, undefined-behavior

I am seeing different results for two program that I expect to produce the same output, the first case:

```
int money;

printf("Enter the price of the car: ");
scanf("%d", &money);

printf("\nResult: %d .\n", money+money*0.4);
```

the second case:

```
int money;

printf("Enter the price of the car: ");
scanf("%d", &money);

money=money+money*0.4;

printf("\nResult: %d .\n", money );
return 0;
```

In the first case the result of the `printf` is `0` but not in the second case. Why am I seeing these different results?

Comment: You should enable warning to understand. In first case it is 

`format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’`

In second case 

 `conversion to ‘int’ from ‘double’ may alter its value`.

And i guess warning explains itself very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`money+money*0.4` will implicitly cast `money` to double and thus make the `%d` a wrong format specifier for that value.

Answer (score 7):

the `%d` format specifier tells `printf` that you are passing in an *int* but in the first case you are passing in a *double* which is also [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and so the results are not reliable. The result of:

```
money+money*0.4
```

is *double* since a *floating constant* is *double* unless it has a suffix such as `f` and the results of the *multiplication* and *addition* are *double* as well due to the *usual arithmetic conversions* which both operations are subject to and which will cause the value of `money` to be converted to *double* for the operation.

In the second case you are correctly passing in *int* and since you are assigning the result to `money`:

```
money=money+money*0.4
```

it will truncate the *double* value. I am not sure what compiler you are using but both `clang` and `gcc` without any warning flags both warn about the incorrect format specifier, `gcc` for example says:

> warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat]

So if you are not seeing any warning for that line you should look into setting your warning levels higher.

For completeness sake the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function*, which also covers `printf` with respect to the format specifiers, In paragraph *9* says:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>248)</sup> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Check the multiplication in line 7.

You could change the last lines to:

```
float price = money * 1.4;
printf( "\nResult %f.\n", price);
```